# Vertical and horizontal center of avatar image after resizing

Tags: ionic2

I have the following code that display small avatars:

```
<ion-avatar *ngFor="let user of item.users;">
  <img src="{{ user.avatar }}" style="max-width:2.5rem; max-height:2.5rem;">
</ion-avatar>
```

As it seems, the default size of ion-avatar is 4rem on 4rem .
The result is that the avatars are aligned to the top left corner of a bigger container (which is fine for me - spacing between the avatars).

How can I make the image to be in the center of the ion-avater continer?

Comment: Try adding `margin: 0 auto; text-align:center` to the img css so as to get your actual image vertically/horizontally aligned within its larger container

Answer (score 2):

you need to set `margin: auto;` in your `*.scss`

in your *.component.ts

```
<ion-avatar class='avatar' *ngFor="let user of item.users;">
  <img src="{{ user.avatar }}" style="max-width:2.5rem; max-height:2.5rem;">
</ion-avatar>
```

in your *.component.scss

```
.avatar img {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class in your `img` tag as shown below

```
<img class="myavt" src="{{ user.avatar }}" style="max-width:2.5rem; max-height:2.5rem;">
```

In your sass page

```
.myavt{
           left: 50%;
         transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this easiest using flexbox...

```
ion-avatar {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```